# Enrich Base Class for different Children

Tags: c#, inheritance

I currently have a problem with inheritance of a base class.
I have different child class, which use the same method to fill all infos of the base class and have their own method to enrich it.
Is there a good solution/pattern for it? My current solution would be AutoMapper.

```
    public class Car
    {
        public IList<Wheels> wheels { get; set; }

        public IList<Windows> Whindows { get; set; }

        public Engine Engine { get; set; }
    }

    public class BMW : Car
    {
        public Navy Navy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tesla : Car
    {
        public Battery Battery { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarFactory
    {       
        public BMW CreateBMW()
        {
            var bmw = (BMW)CreateCar();
            bmw.Navy = navy;
            RemoveTurnSignal();
        }

        public Tesla CreateTesla()
        {
            var tesla = (Tesla)CreateCar();
            tesla.Battery = battery;
        }

        private Car CreateCar()
        {
            var car = new Car();
            car.Wheels = wheels;
            car.Windows = windows;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide your real code? This one is not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `CreateCar` generic:

```
public class CarFactory
{       
    public BMW CreateBMW()
    {
        var bmw = Create<BMW>();
        bmw.Navy = navy;
        RemoveTurnSignal();
        return bmw;
    }

    public Tesla CreateTesla()
    {
        var tesla = Create<Tesla>();
        tesla.Battery = battery;
        return tesla;
    }

    private TCar Create<TCar>() where TCar : Car, new()
    {
        var car = new TCar();
        car.Wheels = wheels;
        car.Windows = windows;
        return car;
    }
}
```

Ensuring that `TCar` is constrained to `Car`, so that you can assign to `Wheels` and `Windows`, and constrained to `new()` so that you can invoke the parameterless constructor.

---

Alternatively, add a constructor to `Car`:

```
public class Car
{
    public IList<Wheels> Wheels { get; set; }
    public IList<Windows> Windows { get; set; }
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }

    public Car(IList<Wheels> wheels, IList<Windows> windows)
    {
        Wheels = wheels;
        Windows = windows;
    }
}
```

Then have your subclasses call that constructor:

```
public class BMW : Car
{
    public Navy Navy { get; set; }

    public BMW(IList<Wheels> wheels, IList<Windows> windows) : base(wheels, windows) { }
}
```

Which would allow you to create a subclass like this:

```
public BMW CreateBMW()
{
    var bmw = new BMW(wheels, windows);
    bmw.Navy = navy;
    RemoveTurnSignal();
    return bmw;
}
```